# What to do if the Mat Expansion Title has no drop down button?

Tags: node.js, angular

I installed a MatExpansionPanel in my angular web page and the drop down arrow is not visible in that panel. Instead the header and the content is visible by default.

I tried copying a piece of code from "Angular Material" site and still unable to fix the problem

```
<mat-accordion>
<mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        MY POSTS
    </mat-expansion-panel-header> 
    <p>Post</p>            
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

I need that drop down option to be enabled

[Piece of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D42i0.jpg)[The panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLN1B.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an stackblitz link (where you can see in live your code).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vqs8j

I'm not sure what is happening to you, but it seems that your code is nice.

Maybe do you forget some imports??
Here is the link with the API for the Expansion panel:
https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api

If you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: I did right it seems. Is there a way to manually enable the drop down button?

Comment: could you press F12? This enables you to see the Developper Window. Maybe there is an error.
When you press F12 go to the `Console` Tab

Comment: That really helped....Resolved the error......Thank U sooooooooooooooooooo much..!!!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you. Mark my answer as correct in other to help other users with the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you hide the button with the 'MY POSTS'. You should use it in this way:
For title:

```
   <mat-panel-title>
    MY POSTS
  </mat-panel-title>
```

For description:

```
  <mat-panel-description>
    Type your description
  </mat-panel-description>
```

Here is the link:
[Angular Material Expansion Panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples)

Comment: But for the tutorial I saw he did exactly the same thing and it's working fine for him